# C# Display data based on userID

Tags: c#, sql

Hi I'm creating a C# program where users can login and book bus seats for destinations, I have the program so users can insert/update/delete data but I want the data to just display the currently logged-in data, this is my code below.

This function is in the main dashboard class where it displays the seats table to the dataviewgrid

```
private void displayBookings()
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = "select * from seats";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            sda.Fill(dt);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
            con.Close();
        }
```

[image]

This is my database table and all I want to do once a user is logged in is display each seatID by the userID, the seatid is the primary key for this table and the userid is a foreign key linked to the userdata table.

EDIT:

```
private void displayBookings()
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"CONNECTIONSTRING");

            SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = "select * from seats WHERE userID = @userID";

            //add the user id as a parameter
            SqlParameter p_userID = new SqlParameter("@userID", SqlDbType.Int);
            // the userID of the logged in user
            p_userID.Value = cmd.Parameters.Add(p_userID);

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            sda.Fill(dt);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
            con.Close();
        }
```

Login method

```
private void loginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            StringBuilder errorMessages = new StringBuilder();
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Brandon Brock\source\repos\SE2\Booking System\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True"))
            {
                con.Open();
                string str1 = "select * from userdata where username='" + log_username.Text + "' and password_1='" + log_password.Text + "'";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(str1, con);
                try
                {
                    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(str1, con);
                    da.SelectCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    da.Fill(dt);
                    if (dt.Rows.Count == 1)
                    {
                        switch (dt.Rows[0]["type"] as string)
                        {
                            case "admin":
                                {
                                    MessageBox.Show("You are logged in!", "Admin Portal", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                                    this.Hide();
                                    new Admin().Show();
                                    break;
                                }
                            case "user":
                                {
                                    MessageBox.Show("You are logged in!", "Seat Reservation", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                                    this.Hide();
                                    new Dashboard().Show();
                                    break;
                                }
                            default:
                                {
                                    MessageBox.Show("Enter Correct Username and Password");
                                    break;
                                }
                        }
                        log_username.Text = "";
                        log_password.Text = "";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Username or Password is wrong or Account doesn't exist!", "Bus Seat Account Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                    }
                }
                catch (SqlException ex)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < ex.Errors.Count; i++)
                    {
                        errorMessages.Append("Index #" + i + "\n" +
                            "Message: " + ex.Errors[i].Message + "\n" +
                            "LineNumber: " + ex.Errors[i].LineNumber + "\n" +
                            "Source: " + ex.Errors[i].Source + "\n" +
                            "Procedure: " + ex.Errors[i].Procedure + "\n");
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine(errorMessages.ToString());
                }
            }
            
            
        }
```

Comment: What is the criteria from being logged in?  there is no column indicating if a user is logged in.

Comment: this line is totally wrong: `p_userID.Value = cmd.Parameters.Add(p_userID);`. The `Value` is the user id which you have not shown, but you will need. So it is a number, like 1 or 117 or 374 or whatever the user id is.

Comment: yeah but I want it to be the session of userid for when any user is logged in it get their personal userid and shows different seat data

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have access to the logged in user data:

```
con.Open(); // <-- can't see where this comes from but is almost certainly an anti-pattern. Don't re-use SqlConnection instances, make new ones and Dispose() when done.

SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.CommandText = "select * from seats WHERE userID = @userID";

//add the user id as a parameter
SqlParameter p_userID = new SqlParameter("@userID", SqlDbType.Int);
p_userID.Value = // the userID of the logged in user
cmd.Parameters.Add(p_userID);

//cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); <-- this is pointless, delete it

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
sda.Fill(dt);
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
con.Close();
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but I'm now getting an error with the failed to convert parameter value from a sqlparameter to a int32

Comment: Could you update your question to show your current code?

Comment: no problem, also added in the login method in case it was a problem with that